# Did Phil Foglio introduce the trope that platypuses don't do anything?

Tags: comics, girl-genius, phineas-and-ferb, myth-adventures

In Phineas and Ferb, the joke is that humans think platypuses don't do anything, and yet Perry is actually a secret agent.  Even though "Perry doesn't do anything," they love him and he's important to them.

Years earlier, Phil Foglio introduced a The Winslow, a platypus-like indestructible reptile who's important to "everyone," but doesn't do anything.

This is the earliest example of this trope that I have found. Is anyone aware of an earlier example?

Comment: Uhhh... much as I'm a fan of Foglio, I'd need a lot more than two examples to say he started a trope.

Comment: @Radhil That’s a good point.  Can you think of another example?

Comment: The Winslow is an alligator, though, not a platypus.

Comment: Platypodes aren't reptiles.

Comment: Of course not.  That’s why I wrote, “platypus-like.”

Comment: How is the Winslow like a platypus? No duck beak, tail’s wrong....

Comment: I'm not really sure that Phineas and Ferb think that Perry doesn't do anything specifically because he is a platypus.  Any animal could be substituted in as the family pet, with little need to change anything.  The show uses a trope of "pets and/or animals are secretly at least as intelligent as humans and have their own hidden (often highly advanced) society".

Comment: Really?  In the song, “Everything’s better with Perry,” the lyrics definitely imply to me that his contribution is blinking his eyes and breathing in and out.

Comment: Phineas and Ferb do say platypuses, specifically, don’t do much. Phineas often says *Well, he is a platypus. They don't do much.* or a similar phrase. He says it in “Toy to the World” when they’re making a toy Perry, for example.

Answer (score 15):

I very much doubt that "Platypuses don't to anything" is popular enough to be a trope, but if it is then it certainly predates Phil Foglio. If there is a trope, and if it has a start point then it is probably the poem ["The Diplomatic Platypus"](https://www.poemhunter.com/poem/the-diplomatic-platypus/), published in Punch magazine in the thirties. While too old to be well-known now, it was extremely popular in its time and for several decades afterwards.

In the poem a platypus is appointed to the British diplomatic service, and proves to be extremely successful, precisely because he doesn't do anything, and therefore never does anything wrong.

> The wisdom of the choice, it soon appeared, was undeniable;
>
> There never was a diplomat more thoroughly reliable.
>
> He never made rash statements his enemies might hold him to,
>
> He never stated anything, for no one ever told him to,